# Upload de dados binárias via post sem html

Tags: php, http-request

Eu queria uma solução para fazer exatamente o que este html faz, contudo usando apenas php: upload de um dado binário e campos normais (strings).

```
<center>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://10.40.0.241/api/mailingup/index.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="9000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uploading" value="42">

    <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr><td>Login</td><td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Senha</td><td><input type="text" name="senha"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Auto DDD</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="auto_ddd"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>DDD</td><td><input type="text" name="ddd"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="option1">Campanha ID</td><td class="option1"><input type="text" name="CampanhaId"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="option2">Arquivo</td><td class="option2"><input type="file" name="arquivo" style="width:500px;"></td></tr>

    </table>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Salvar" VALUE="Carregar" onclick="SalvarOperador();">
</form>
```

Fiz um código mas não funcionou.

```
<?php

$arq = fopen("teste.csv", 'rb');
$fileContents = stream_get_contents($arq);
fclose($arq);

$campos = array(
    "login" => "rafael",
    "senha" => "master",
    "CampanhaId" => "177",
    "arquivo" => $fileContents,
    "uploading" => "42",
    "auto_ddd" => "on",
    "ddd" => "21"
);


$content = http_build_query($campos);

$context = stream_context_create(
        array(
        "http" => array(
                'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $content
            )
        )
    );
$url = 'http://10.40.0.241/api/mailingup/index.php';

$fp = fopen($url, 'rb',false,$context);
echo stream_get_contents($fp);
```

?>

Comment: Tá querendo fazer um upload de script para script?

Comment: Isso mesmo, @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer na verdade é fazer uma requisição remota através de um script PHP, enviando um arquivo junto a essa requisição.

Eu tenho duas opções a oferecer:

## Upload de arquivos com a biblioteca Guzzle\Http

Uma forma que conheço de fazer upload utilizando apenas um cliente PHP é através do Guzzle.

Veja:

```
$body = fopen('/arquivo.txt', 'r');
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', ['body' => $body]);
```

Veja que não tem muito segredo. Nesse caso, ele vai enviar um `stream` baseado no arquivo que foi aberto.

Essa `stream` poderia também ser uma `string` qualquer. Veja:

```
$body = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for('hello!');
 $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', ['body' => $body]);
```

Para instalar o Guzzle, você pode utilizar o Composer.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Se estiver curioso pra saber como a biblioteca faz para realizar esse procedimento, você pode olhar o [repositório no Github](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

## Upload de arquivos na unha

Para poder fazer esse código *na cara e na coragem*, a linha de raciocínio é realmente usar `stream_context_create`.
Mas no caso, você deve configurar o `Content-Type` corretamente.
Quando se trata de upload, você não usa `x-www-form-urlencoded`, e sim `multipart/form-data`.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--foo\r\n",
        "content" => "--foo\r\n"
            . "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
            . file_get_contents("image.jpg") . "\r\n"
            . "--foo--"
    )
));

$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/upload.php", false, $context);
```

Código acima foi retirado do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227923/php-convert-file-to-binary-and-send-it-using-http-post)

Comment: Ajudou amigo. você saberia dar o mesmo exemplo usando a biblioteca cURL ?

Comment: Posso dar uma pesquisada e postar mas como estou no celular isso pode demorar umas 2 horas ;)

Comment: Eu te amo, cara.